# Certain object values not accessible in ejs loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to solve a problem with accessing all the values of some javascript objects inside a forEach loop with ejs.

Using the following.....

```
            <ul>
                <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>

                          <li><%= user %></li>

                <% }); %>
            </ul>
```

Displays the objects correctly as a list like so..

```
{ _id: 55907b9a84218bf511000001, __v: 0, bio: 'awesome bio', name: 'Joe Bloggs', email: 'joe@mail.com'}
{ _id: 5590818fba82f6e31a000001, bio: 'Another great bio', name: 'Rose', email: 'rosey@mail.com' }
```

And using....

```
            <ul>
                <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>

                          <li><%= user.id %></li>

                <% }); %>
            </ul>
```

Displays only the object id's as expected like so....

```
55907b9a84218bf511000001
5590818fba82f6e31a000001
```

The problem is when I try to access the 'name' or 'email' values using

```
<li><%= user.name %></li>
<li><%= user.email %></li>
```

Results in 'undefined' even though I know the values are reaching the view correctly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `user._doc.name` and `user._doc.email`?

Comment: How are you passing the array of users  to your template?

Comment: Thanks @mscdex that fixed it. Haven't seen that used before. If you could possibly tell me why _doc is needed to access the those values but not user.id I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @BidhanA thanks for response. Just so it's clear for anyone else with a similar issue, i was simply passing the user data returned in the requests callback function like this `res.render('index.ejs', { users : users } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose Document instances don't actually store the data directly on the document instance itself because it has special getters/setters to make sure everything is consistent if the document is used in other Mongoose method calls.

The getters/setters use the `_doc` object for actual value storage, but you can also call `toObject()` to return a plain js object containing the expected document values.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Just one more thing is puzzling me. I have another app instance retrieving the data from mongodb via mongoose in exactly the same way which displays all the properties using regular dot notation `<%= user.name %>`. Under what circumstances does it work? The only real difference in the app where it works is I am using the express router format `router.route('/users').get(function(req,res)` as opposed to regular `app.get('/users)`. I also tried matching all the dependencies between the two apps(one has more recent mongoose) but the problem persists.